# Build multiple executables with small changes in objects

Tags: makefile

Consider the following Makefile

```
COMP = compiler

OBJECTS =   file1 \
        file2 \
        file3 \
        file4 \
        file5_suffix \
        file6 \
        file7 \
        file8 \
        file9_suffix \
        file10

all:    $(OBJECTS) 
        $(COMP) $(OBJECTS) -o bin/executable_suffix
```

Is there an easy way to compile multiple executables for different values of `suffix`? For example, the equivalent of

```
COMP = compiler

OBJECTS1 =  file1 \
        file2 \
        file3 \
        file4 \
        file5_s1 \
        file6 \
        file7 \
        file8 \
        file9_s1 \
        file10

OBJECTS2 =  file1 \
        file2 \
        file3 \
        file4 \
        file5_s2 \
        file6 \
        file7 \
        file8 \
        file9_s2 \
        file10

all:    $(OBJECTS1) $(OBJECTS2) 
        $(COMP) $(OBJECTS1) -o bin/executable_s1
        $(COMP) $(OBJECTS2) -o bin/executable_s2
```

but without redefining the whole list of objects? In the real life case I am dealing with, there might be 50+ objects and a dozen binaries to build, with only small changes between the object list each time, so it would be nice not to have to list all the objects each time.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. It can be made more elegant if there are more restrictions you can put on the variations.

```
COMP = compiler

OBJECTS =  file1 \
    file2 \
    file3 \
    file4 \
    file5 \
    file6 \
    file7 \
    file8 \
    file9 \
    file10

# This isn't terribly elegant, but it is quite general.
# If the variations you have in mind are more regular, such as
# changing only file5 and file9 for all executables, then there
# are tidier ways to do it.
OBJECTS1 := $(OBJECTS)
OBJECTS1 := $(patsubst file5,file5_s1,$(OBJECTS1))
OBJECTS1 := $(patsubst file9,file9_s1,$(OBJECTS1))

OBJECTS2 := $(OBJECTS)
OBJECTS2 := $(patsubst file5,file5_s2,$(OBJECTS2))
OBJECTS2 := $(patsubst file9,file9_s2,$(OBJECTS2))

all: bin/executable_s1 bin/executable_s2

# It looks a little clumsy to include the path in the target,
# but the idea is that the target should be what it's actually making,
# which is bin/executable_s1, not executable_s1.

bin/executable_s1: $(OBJECTS1)
bin/executable_s2: $(OBJECTS2)

bin/executable_%:
    $(COMP) $^ -o $@
```